# List view in Calendar

Tags: calendar, ios

How do I get and keep the Calendar app in IOS 9 to say in list view.

My phone changes to the yearly view i.e. first 9 months of the  year and shows no list icon

This is on iPhone 4S

Pressing today else seems to do nothing. (todays date is still off the screen)
[image]

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do? Do you just want to see the list of your appointments, instead of the whole calendar? If so, just press "Today" in Calendar (bottom-left) and a list of all your next appointments is shown.

Comment: This annoys me as well.  I don't want it to jump into list view but I'm annoyed that it starts in the year overview instead of automatically loading the day.  Maybe it's an issue with the 4s since that is the phone I have as well.  I don't see any option in the settings to change the default either.  I'm on OS 9.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the iOS 9 Calendar app, there are two ways to get to the list view for today.

Solution 1:

> From the Home screen,
>
> 1. Open `Calendar.app`
> 2. Click `Today`
> 3. If you can't see the current month because you're on a 3.5" screen, scroll down
> 4. Click on the current month (in this case, it's `DEC`)
> 5. Click the red circle (in this case, it's the `13`)

Solution 2:

> From the Home screen,
>
> 1. Open `Calendar.app`
> 2. Click any month
> 3. Click any day
> 4. Click `Today`

You're now at the list view for today. If it's not in your desired version of the list view, toggle the `List` icon in the top-right corner of the screen (represented by three dots next to three lines)

Closing the app and re-opening it will take you to the last view it was at before it closed (this is true even if the app gets closed completely by swiping up on it the App Switcher.) And if your last view happened to be the `Today` for that day, it will automatically jump you to the current date when you re-open the app.

Comment: I always navigate to "Today" and I'm guessing after a while once calendar has been pushed out of RAM and I open it later it goes back to year view  The question is WTF does it go back to year view and is there any way to change that?  It's really annoying to have to go through these steps and why the hell can't it remember that the last place I was WASN'T year view.

Comment: After seeing your edit I would LOVE to believe that's the way the calendar works but I NEVER go back to year view and it almost always loads in year view.  I'm on a 4S so maybe things are different but I would love to know why they are different and if there is anything I can do about it.

Comment: I tried it on both of my iOS 9 devices (an iPhone 5s and an iPhone 4s). It always opened back up to the last view I was in even if I swiped up on the app in the App Switcher. Try it yourself.

Comment: Well I don't know why it acts the way it does but sure if I close it by swiping up on the app switcher it will open to the last place it was.  But the first time I open it after I haven't used it for a while it definitely always opens to the year view.  It's annoying.

Comment: @Dason it definitely does do as you say

Comment: 1 and 2 does not work (now on a 6s) the month shows and it only shows the events for the day. The list switches between month + events for the day or month and next month. However the point re the off screen is part of the answer

Comment: It seems to be the extra click on today that the other answer mentions that is the key

Comment: Doesn't fix the issue for me but it's the best answer presented so far so you get my bounty.

Answer (score 1):

This one stumped me too for a while but when I tap on today's date in the calendar it zooms to the month view. Tap on today's date **again** and it pops into list view.

At least it does on my iPhone 6+ with IOS 9

Comment: But todays's date is not on screen in my case and tapping on Today does nothing

Comment: @Mark - Same thing for me.  The "today" button will take you to the current date but only if you're in month or day mode.  I think it might be an oversight by the developers and they are assuming that the phones can display the entire year on the screen but on the 4S there isn't enough screen space.  If you move to a different year and hit the Today button it takes you to the current year but since we're late in the year the current date isn't on screen.

Comment: For an iPhome4S it does not do this e.g. a date on November does not allow you to tap on the date